# Converting double?[ ] to object[ ] in c#

Tags: c#, linq, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am using DotNet.Highcharts in my C# program. The data element for series  items requires an `object[]`. The data I’m using is coming from a LINQ method as shown below. The code below also converts the `double?[]` to a `List<object>` then to the desired `object[]`.

```
double?[] data = (from c in context.CTSeries
                 select c.CTDI).Take(1000).ToArray();

List<object> dataList = new List<object>();

foreach (double? ctdi in data)
{
    dataList.Add( Convert.ChangeType(ctdi, typeof(Object)));
}

object[] dataArray = dataList.ToArray();
return dataArray;
```

Is there a better/more efficient way of getting the `object[]` from a `double?[]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use LINQ and cast `double?` to `object`

```
List<object> dataList = data.Select(d => (object)d).ToList();
```

or  to return an array

```
return data.Select(d=> (object)d).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just `Cast<object>()` instead of creating extra intermediate array:

```
 double?[] data = (from c in context.CTSeries
                     select c.CTDI).Take(1000)
     .Where(v => v.HasValue) // if needed
     .Cast<object>()
     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<object> dataList = data.Select(d =>  d == null ? null : (object)d).ToList();
```