# Live Charts AddRange not working with arrays or Series Collection

Tags: c#, livecharts

I am trying to create a light-as-possible real-time plotter with [Live Charts Geared WPF](https://lvcharts.net/licensing/pricing), sampling roughly 125 points a second. Adding point-by-point regularly works just fine, except that CPU utilization is much too high.

I would like to draw several points at once, reading in values from a buffer, similar to the website example:

```
var temporalCv = new double[1000];

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    temporalCv[i] = 5;
}

var cv = new ChartValues<double>();
cv.AddRange(temporalCv);
```

By itself, the example does not throw any issues.
However, it throws a cannot convert from `double[]` to `Systems.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Object>`  when I want to `AddRange` to `ChartValues` and `GearedValues` below.

```
SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new GLineSeries
                {
                    Title = "Pressure",
                    Values = new GearedValues<double> {},

                },
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Title = "Pulse",
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { },
                }
            };

SeriesCollection[1].Values.AddRange(temporalCv);
```

I have also tried changing the array to a `GearedValue<double>` type but it will still throw the issue when I want to add double values to the array.

Is there anyway to convert `double[]` or another way to add multiple points to the plot together without erasing old points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

It looks like someone else has already asked a similar question here:  [Convert List<double> to LiveCharts.IChartValues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954967/convert-listdouble-to-livecharts-ichartvalues)

You will need to convert your `double[]` to an `IEnumerable<double>` before you can convert it to an `IChartValues` collection.  This can be easily done with the `ToList` extension method from `System.Linq`:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var chartValues = temporalCv.ToList().AsChartValues();
SeriesCollection[1].Values.AddRange(chartValues);
```

I do not have LiveCharts so I cannot test this directly.  You may only need to convert `temporalCv` to a list and let `AddRange` do the rest:

```
var chartValues = temporalCv.ToList();
```

Comment: So I just changed it to a List instead of array, but AddRange needs an IEnum<object>. I have tried casting and changing it to ChartValues, but the closest I can get it to is IEnum<double>. At least to my understanding, I will have to have an object list and wrap all my inputted doubles as an object?

Comment: This works from array to object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922940/converting-double-to-object-in-c-sharp